# Sort MySQL rows by column, but not alphabetically

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the title is a bit ambiguous and reminiscent of other semi-related questions), the issue is in fact quite simple.

I have a VARCHAR column which can have 1-character values such as `M,G,D and S`. If I sort the results alphabetically, in this example it will show them in the order: `D-G-M-S`. However, I need to display the rows in the following order:

```
G-D-M-S
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within the query? I know I can custom-sort the results in PHP, but I'd rather do it within the query if possible. For this example, I just need to switch the order of "G" and "D" in the results, and the solution to that simplistic problem will suffice for any answers.

Comment: How do you know what order they are supposed to be in?

Comment: It seems that if the database is supposed to know about the order, than add an `order_index` column or something like that to the table. If the database is not supposed to know about the order, then do it on the PHP side, perhaps in a config file. I might have the wrong idea, since I don't know much about your situation, but that would be my inclination.

Comment: @ExplosionPills The task here is just to switch the order of G and D in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your custom `case` statement:

```
Select *
from your_table
order by
   case your_column 
     when 'G' then 1
     when 'D' then 2
     when 'M' then 3
     when 'S' then 4
   end
```

Also, another solution, is to change collation at physical level:

[Change default Sorting by Adding a Simple Collation to an 8-Bit Character Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036621/change-default-sorting-by-adding-a-simple-collation-to-an-8-bit-character-set)

Comment: I don't want to mess with the collation, I just need this switch on one column in one table. The case thing looks like the solution I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: I don't suggest to you change collation, I only say that exists this possibility, and also, you can create your own collations. Change collation is a solution only if you need high performance.

Comment: Do you think the `case` statement would be quicker than adding another column to the table with indexes for each letter (1 for G, 2 for D etc) and using that to sort?

Comment: The case statement means that the RDBMS will scan all rows to sort it, it must to evaluate case expression row by row. If you take only few rows there is not a problem. A new column with values it is easily indexed, but perhaps RDBMS don't need this index (see previous sentence)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is define a temp or permanent table with 2 columns :

```
letter  |  ordernum
-------------------
G       |  1
D       |  2
M       |  3
S       |  4
```

Then you join your exiting table to that new one on the field "letter", and use the new table "ordernum" field to do the sort...

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm gonna go with the `case` statement from danihp's answer (although I see this would work too, I'd rather avoid the extra table).

Comment: It depends if you rather update your DB or your code (query) if a new value comes in... I'm working in an environment where it's easier to deploy/change DB than code so...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    if(columnname='G',1,
        if(columnname='D',2,
            if(columnname='M',3,
                if(columnname='S',4,0
    )))) SortOrder
FROM tablename
ORDER BY
    SortOrder ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select col from table 
   order by case when col = 'G' then 1 
   when col = 'D' then 2
   when col = 'M' then 3 
   case when col = 'S' then 4 else 5 end ;
```